# Exclude or delete directory path from %files in rpm.spec file

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

My spec files path looks like below :

```
/opt/OV
/opt/OV/NonOV
/opt/OV/NonOV/ABCD
/opt/OV/NonOV/ABCD/ABC
/opt/OV/NonOV/ABCD/ABC/Test1
/opt/OV/NonOV/ABCD/ABC/Test1/test1.txt
/opt/OV/NonOV/ABCD/ABC/Test2
/opt/OV/NonOV/ABCD/ABC/Test2/test2.txt
/opt/OV/newconfig
/opt/OV/newconfig/inventory
/opt/OV/newconfig/inventory/HPOvXYZ.xml
```

I don't want to this path to be included in spec file 
`/opt/OV/newconfig/inventory`" because if more than one rpm has this common path it gives error "conflict with file from package."

I have checked with `%excludes` command like below:

```
%files
%exclude /opt/OV/newconfig/inventory
```

So problem with this command is, it is excluding directly and files recursively. The rpm.spec files path look like this:

```
/opt/OV
/opt/OV/NonOV
/opt/OV/NonOV/ABCD
/opt/OV/NonOV/ABCD/ABC
/opt/OV/NonOV/ABCD/ABC/Test1
/opt/OV/NonOV/ABCD/ABC/Test1/test1.txt
/opt/OV/NonOV/ABCD/ABC/Test2
/opt/OV/NonOV/ABCD/ABC/Test2/test2.txt
/opt/OV/newconfig
```

It is excluding `/opt/OV/newconfig/inventory/HPOvXYZ.xml` this path as well.
Is there any command so the I an exclude/delete only directory path.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 12):

```
%files
/opt/OV
%exclude %dir /opt/OV/newconfig/inventory
```

This will leave `/opt/OV/newconfig/inventory/HPOvXYZ.xml` in the file list.